# Difficulty understand iteration through a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding how iteration is implemented with a for each loop to allow my code to go through each entry in a LinkedList and print the output to the console.

My MainMenu.java class contains

```
private MainMenu parent;
private LinkedList<Order> orders;
```

and my FillDlg.java contains a similar structure, MainMenu is a parent of FillDlg. they are both windows

[image]
[image]

I tried the following code and modifications of it but I get the error

```
                    Iterator itr = orders.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Object element = itr.next();
            System.out.println(element + " ");

            System.out.println(order);

    }
```

***Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FillDlg.actionPerformed(FillDlg.java:92)***

The rest of the classes such as Order.java are just constructors and accessors, the main issue is getting the iterator to use the LinkedList from MainMenu.java to FillDlg.java

The Line 92 error is the orders.iterator (LinkedList FillDlg.orders) line

the list contains a bunch of Order objects `orders.add(new Order(orderID, items.get(item), customers.get(customer), quantity, timeStamp));`

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does the error message correspond to the code you show? Where os this line 92 in FillDlg? And what is the content of the list?

Comment: Line 92: is the for orders loop you can see.
the list contains a bunch of Order objects 

`orders.add(new Order(orderID, items.get(item), customers.get(customer), quantity, timeStamp));`

Comment: Ryan, please update the question to include your above comment. And having your code posted helps us.

Comment: Just one remark, when you solve your NPE you will end up with ConcurrentModificationException because you are trying add element into LinkedList while iterating it.

Answer (score 0):

The list is `null` because it hadn't been initialized; initialize it:

```
private LinkedList<Order> orders = new LinkedList<>();
```